# Virtual disk, iso file o some kind of superfolder

Tags: linux, windows, iso-image, vhdx

I lookin for some kind of solution for several needs, It would be wonderful if I find one for everything, or at least several.
My needs:

- I want to make backups to my linux servers from another linux and windows, so I need a folder or similar that can be easily mount, so I can share with samba, can be heavily compress and in some cases encrypt.
- That can be copy to other systems without major complications, other linux o windows.
- Preferably that can be see a treat as a single file, when not mounted. For easy copy and move.
- That the content can't be hide form Antivirus and similar, so I can run an AV to the file and can't see what's inside.
- Finally and most important that there is opensoftware to work with in linux and windows. Not necessarily the same one.

First I think an iso file, but i can't find and easy way to throw a file in the and the system compress it.
Now I start vhdx files, but they must have filesystem, and I prefere they don't, since windows and linux don't have any modern filesystem that can be share.

So nay other option or new ideas about the first two will be apreciate.
Thank

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clean what you are asking but if you skip over the Windows requirement, you can cover most of those points using a user-space file-system (FUSE):

- Create a file system inside a file
- Simply copy the file when you want it on another system
- Mount the file when you want to perform a backup: This lets you use any backup tool and even supports incremental backups via something like `rsync`
- Mount the file when you want to access its content
- Set user and access permissions to control access

While in theory the antivirus can run on such a file, it may not function properly without mounting first, depending on the file-system. You can work with it as any other file-system, the only difference is that `-o loop` is required
to mount it when calling `mount`.